# What is a strict alternative to __doPostBack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dopostback

I'm working on fixing a piece of legacy javascript code left from an ex-employee.  The legacy code alters the DOM of automatically pregenerated HTML and adds in some functionality to the submit button by hijacking its submission with an onClick.  The function that the onClick calls runs some needed business logic and then finishes it up with a `__doPostBack()` call.

The problem is that he's using a lot of libraries with 'use strict', and that `__doPostBack()` call only works on Chrome.

Not wanting to completely redo this code ... is there a strict alternative to `__doPostBack()`?  Or is it just too risky because of the security impact?

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13335

Comment: Why would the `__doPostBack` function itself need to become strict? What security impact are you talking about?

Comment: @Bergi I have never used the `__doPostBack` function before, so I've just been trying to look it up online, and I've been seeing people commenting on it being bad for security.  I can think of a lot of ways someone can misuse that sort of functionality, but I really am not certain.  I've never looked too closely at it til yesterday.